# MongoDB, PHP getting unique visitors per day

Tags: php, mongodb, mapreduce, distinct

I'm creating some analytics script using PHP and MongoDB and I am a bit stuck. I would like to get the unique number of visitors per day within a certain time frame.

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("523768039b7e7a1505000000"),
   "ipAddress": "127.0.0.1",
   "pageId": ObjectId("522f80f59b7e7a0f2b000000"),
   "uniqueVisitorId": "0445905a-4015-4b70-a8ef-b339ab7836f1",
   "recordedTime": ISODate("2013-09-16T20:20:19.0Z") 
}
```

The field to filter on is uniqueVisitorId and recordedTime.

I've created a database object in PHP that I initialise and it makes me a database connection when the object is constructed, then I have MongoDB php functions simply mapped to public function using the database connection created on object construction.

Anyhow, so far I get the number of visitors per day with:

```
public function GetUniqueVisitorsDiagram() {
    // MAP
    $map = new MongoCode('function() {
        day = new Date(Date.UTC(this.recordedTime.getFullYear(), this.recordedTime.getMonth(), this.recordedTime.getDate()));
        emit({day: day, uniqueVisitorId:this.uniqueVisitorId},{count:1});
    }');
    // REDUCE
    $reduce = new MongoCode("function(key, values) {
            var count = 0;
            values.forEach(function(v) {
                count += v['count'];
            });
            return {count: count};
        }");
    // STATS
    $stats = $this->database->Command(array(
        'mapreduce' => 'statistics',
        'map' => $map,
        'reduce' => $reduce,
        "query" => array(
            "recordedTime" =>
                array(
                    '$gte' => $this->startDate,
                    '$lte' => $this->endDate
                )
            ),
            "out" => array(
                "inline" => 1
            )
        ));
    return $stats;          
}
```

How would I filter this data correctly to get unique visitors? Or would it better to use aggregation, if so could you be so kind to help me out with a code snippet?

Comment: I would strongly recommend you do not run Map Reduce inline to your application, look into the aggregation framework or something

Comment: How would you do the aggregation? As it looks to me I can't do it filtering that easy with the aggregation framework, to me it looks like I would need to execute two reques.

Comment: To filter: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/match/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $m=new MongoClient();
    $db=$m->super_test;
    $db->gjgjgjg->insert(array(
        "ipAddress" => "127.0.0.1",
        "pageId" => new MongoId("522f80f59b7e7a0f2b000000"),
        "uniqueVisitorId" => "0445905a-4015-4b70-a8ef-b339ab7836f1",
        "recordedTime" => new MongoDate(strtotime("2013-09-16T20:20:19.0Z"))
    ));
    var_dump($db->gjgjgjg->find(array('recordedTime'=>array('$lte'=>new MongoDate(),'$gte'=>new MongoDate(strtotime('-1 week')))))->count()); // Prints 1
    $res=$db->gjgjgjg->aggregate(array(
            array('$match'=>array('recordedTime'=>array('$lte'=>new MongoDate(),'$gte'=>new MongoDate(strtotime('-1 week'))),'uniqueVisitorId'=>array('$ne'=>null))),
            array('$project'=>array('day'=>array('$dayOfMonth'=>'$recordedTime'),'month'=>array('$month'=>'$recordedTime'),'year'=>array('$year'=>'$recordedTime'))),
            array('$group'=>array('_id'=>array('day'=>'$day','month'=>'$month','year'=>'$year'), 'c'=>array('$sum'=>1)))
    )); 
    var_dump($res['result']);
```

To answer the question entirely:

```
    $m=new MongoClient();
    $db=$m->super_test;
    $db->gjgjgjg->insert(array(
        "ipAddress" => "127.0.0.1",
        "pageId" => new MongoId("522f80f59b7e7a0f2b000000"),
        "uniqueVisitorId" => "0445905a-4015-4b70-a8ef-b339ab7836f1",
        "recordedTime" => new MongoDate(strtotime("2013-09-16T20:20:19.0Z"))
    ));
    var_dump($db->gjgjgjg->find(array('recordedTime'=>array('$lte'=>new MongoDate(),'$gte'=>new MongoDate(strtotime('-1 week')))))->count()); // Prints 1
    $res=$db->gjgjgjg->aggregate(array(
            array('$match'=>array('recordedTime'=>array('$lte'=>new MongoDate(),'$gte'=>new MongoDate(strtotime('-1 week'))),'uniqueVisitorId'=>array('$ne'=>null))),
            array('$project'=>array('day'=>array('$dayOfMonth'=>'$recordedTime'),'month'=>array('$month'=>'$recordedTime'),'year'=>array('$year'=>'$recordedTime'))),
            array('$group'=>array('_id'=>array('day'=>'$day','month'=>'$month','year'=>'$year','v'=>'$uniqueVisitorId'), 'c'=>array('$sum'=>1))),
            array('$group'=>array('_id'=>array('day'=>'$_id.day','month'=>'$_id.month','year'=>'$_id.year'),'c'=>array('$sum'=>1)))
    )); 
    var_dump($res['result']);
```

Something close to that is what your looking for I believe.

It will reutrn a set of documents that have the `_id` as the date and then the count of unique visitors for that day irresptive of the of the id, it simply detects only if the id is there.

Since you want it per day you can actually exchange the dat parts for just one field of `$dayOfYear` I reckon.

Comment: Hi @sammaye, thanks for your feedback.

Using what you posted I managed to get some information back from Mongo. However when I add the $match criteria it stops working. Any idea?

$criterea = array(
    array(
 '$project' => array(
            'day' => array('$dayOfMonth'=>'$recordedTime'),
     'month' => array('$month'=>'$recordedTime'),
     'year' => array('$year'=>'$recordedTime')
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$group' => array(
        '_id' => array(
     'day' => '$day',
     'month' => '$month',
     'year' => '$year'
 ),
 'c' => array(
     '$sum'=>1
     )
        )
    )
);

Comment: I've tried to add the "$match" as a second parameter to the aggregation function in PHP but what I get back is an error: pipeline element 0 is not an object, without the the second argument and without the $match it works wine, but I get too much data back.

Comment: @MarcWitteveen Yeah match is a operator in the aggregation framework, let's break down the $match, if you take out the `uniqueVisitorId` clause what happens? Also make sure you are putting a `MongoDate` into the start and end end date. If you try the query separately in a `find()` does it work?

Comment: When I do (see code below) I get the previous mentioned error:
`$criterea = array(
   array(
    '$project' => array(
              ....
    )
      ),
   array(
          '$group' => array(
              ....
     ),
     'c' => array(
      ....
     )
            )
   )
  );
   
   
  $op = array(
    '$match' => array(
     'recordedTime' => array(
      '$gte' => $this->startDate,
      '$lte' => $this->endDate
     )
    )
   );
  
  
   
  $stats = $this->database->Aggregate("statistics", $criterea, $op);`

Comment: The aggregate function looks like:

`public function Aggregate($collection, $criteria, $op = array()) {
   $db = $this->dbObject;
   try {
       $cursor = $db->$collection->aggregate($criteria, $op);
       return $cursor;
   }  catch (Exception $e) {
       $this->errorLog[] = $e->getMessage();
   }   
}`

When I use the $match part ONLY as a criteria the filter works and I get databack between the two dates.

Comment: @MarcWitteveen Where are you getting that info from? That isn't what it looks like in the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php

Comment: @MarcWitteveen I just tried it exactly as I show it above and it works

Comment: Interesting, including the match part? Could you be so kind to share your php file with me?

Comment: @MarcWitteveen That was the exact test script, in the edit I just made

Comment: Here is the code that I have at the moment.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11034612/test.php

Comment: @MarcWitteveen Some of that looks right, ok instead of solving the errors there I have made a full test script, it inserts and everything, this should return data

Comment: @MarcWitteveen Ah I kow why your second aggregation in that file didn't work, you are searching by strings against ISODate()s, you need to use the MongoDate object using strtotime

Comment: Could you send me your script with inserts please? So I can compare it to see where I go wrong?

Comment: @MarcWitteveen Check the edit above, I got a fully fledged version there#

Comment: Found it! Thanks a lot! That one seems to work, I see what you did and how it works. The only thing that does not work is returning the unique  visitors per day, instead it returns the total visitors per day. A visitor is identified via a uniqueVisitorId, but he or she can visit the page e.g. 7 times in a day, but I should only return 1 here, so i think I should put another group in, by uniqueVisitorId?

Comment: @MarcWitteveen Ah I see now so all 7 could have the unique visitor ID but you only want to return one count per each? Do you want it grouped on unique visitor as well as day or do you want it atm but counting only unqiue visits?

Comment: When someone visits my page he gets a cookie set with a unique id or visitorId, unless it is cleared this cookie is valid for 2 years.A new visitor will obvious get another visitorId. If a user uses a different browser then I could obvious filter on IP... but lets ignore that for now.

Now regarding the return data. During a certain timeframe, e.g. a week there are 14 unique visitors. On Monday there are 6 unique visitors, wednesday there are 5 and on thursday there are 3. So the data that should be returned should look like: 2013-09-14 => int(6), 2013-09-16 => int(5), 2013-09-17 => int(3).

Comment: @MarcWitteveen Ok yes, as you said you will need two groupings, one to group by day and unique visitor and then another group by day again, I think that's the best method, with my site personally I actually mark a row as unique visit, this makes this stuff a lot easier

Comment: @MarcWitteveen The second clump of code added on latest edit works for me

Comment: It's becoming quite a space shuttle now. When I change the uniqueVisitorId the counter c stays to 1. Maybe it's better to store in the cookie also the number of times the user visited and insert this into the record as well so I could just say NumberOfVisits > 1.

Comment: @MarcWitteveen That is one way, on my site personally I house a `user` row in a `analytics` collection stored by `day`, there I store a `sessionId`/`userId` which is either the PHP Session ID or the users own ID. Since a visit can only be unique once I store another field on the user analytics row of `unique` boolean, the PHP Session ID cookie can last a long time, when it expires due to time or another user coming along I just class that as another unique view, most analytical sites do as well

Comment: One more thing, how can you sort on day, month year?
I've tried the following with and without $
array('$sort' => array('$day' => 1, '$month' => 1, '$year' => 1))

Comment: @MarcWitteveen Indeed :)

Answer (score 4):

The $group operator in the aggregation framework was designed for exactly this use case and will likely be ~10 to 100 times faster. Read up on the group operator here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/

And the php driver implementation here: http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php

You can combine the $group operator with other operators to further limit your aggregations. It's probably best you do some reading up on the framework yourself to better understand what's happening, so I'm not going to post a complete example for you.