# mongodb php count unique ips per day

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

i have a similar "problem":
[MongoDB, PHP getting unique visitors per day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859528/mongodb-php-getting-unique-visitors-per-day)

My php query:

```
array(
array('$match' => array('date' => array('$gte' => $dateStart, '$lte' => $dateEnd))),
array('$project' => array('day' => array('$dayOfMonth' => '$date'))),
array('$group' => array('_id' => array('day' => '$day', 'uniqueVisitors' => '$ip'), 'count' => array('$sum' => 1))),
array('$group' => array('_id' => array('day' => '$_id.day'), 'count' => array('$sum' => 1))),
array('$sort' => array('_id.day' => 1)),
);
```

Thats shows only 1 as count, if i remove the second group array, i get the ip count but not unique. Can anybody see my failure? :(

Best regards,

Comment: Post one mongo document.

Answer (score 0):

There are some un-necessary steps in the code you are copying from, so basically your pipeline should come out as this

```
    $pipeline = array(
        array( 
            '$match' => array(
                'date' => array('$gte' => $dateStart, '$lte' => $dateEnd )
            )
        ),
        array(
            '$group' => array( 
                '_id' => array(
                    'day' => array( '$dayOfMonth' => '$date' ), 
                    'uniqueVisitors' => '$ip'
                )
            )
        ),
        array(
            '$group' => array(
                '_id' => '$_id.day', 
                'count' => array('$sum' => 1)
            )
        ),
        array( '$sort' => array('_id' => 1) )
    );
```

The first [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) narrows down the actual unique "ip" values per day of month in the rage. Presuming you have a single month in the range or otherwise use [**`$dayOfYear`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfYear/).

Now that those items are "unique" in the pipeline documents, you just change the grouping to the "day" and then "count" those entries via [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/).

Aside from the unnecessary steps there really is nothing wrong with the query itself. You "match" the documents, "group" them down to "unique ip per day" and then get the "count" of those unique matches.

---

Since your main issue seems to be with selecting the date range here is a little PHP snippet to demonstrate a few things:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$dt = new DateTime("2014-02-01", new DateTimeZone('PST'));
echo var_dump( $dt );

echo $dt->getTimestamp(), "\n";

$mongo = new MongoDate( $dt->getTimestamp() );

echo var_dump( $mongo );
echo json_encode( array( $mongo->sec ), "\n";

#echo $mongo->sec, "\n";

$new = new DateTime( date('Y-m-d', $mongo->sec ), new DateTimeZone('PST'));

echo var_dump ($new);

?>
```

That is basically a bit of "there and back again" logic. But essentially I was forcing a new date with a specific Timezone to be created. Then when calling to MongoDate we use the `getTimetamp()` method which returns seconds since epoch as a feeder for the constructor. This is always in UTC by definition and therefore you have an easy conversion.

Comment: Thank you for clean up, thats work. But when i group by month get another count as by day and sum up? I guess this is maybe an problem by timezone? MongoDB UTC Germany UTC+1 and +1 for summertime.

Comment: @Bodenhaltung You generally should convert to straight UTC when issuing queries. So if you take input with dates for a given locale in a different timezone these need to be converted as UTC, which is how MongoDB stores them. Pretty much for the reason that this is good practice and it is your code that should be handling the locale translation.

Comment: Thank you, can you give a example? `$dateStart = new MongoDate(strtotime("first day of now 00:00:00"));
$dateEnd = new MongoDate(strtotime("last day of now 23:59:59"));` But there is a difference from 2 hours in the results, a new day starts at 22:00 in my timezone :(

Comment: `$d = new MongoDate();
echo date("d.m.y H:i:s", $d->sec);` Shows the correct time for my timezone, so i have here add a 2h diff for the mongo query?

Comment: @Bodenhaltung Added a little snippet I have lying around to demonstrate date conversions.